# I can't upload images to my website. How can I fix?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

When I get the picture from the url, I can put it on my site, but I cannot upload it from my pc.
Can you explain to me how Laravel uses src?

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
    <img src=" /img/manzara.jpg " class="card-img" alt="...">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a from for uploadin right?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please at least add some code of what you have done. Give us some insight of your code then we can try to fix your problem. For starter please edit your question and include code of your form and snippet of your controller where you are handling this form request.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I updated my question and added sample codes.

Comment: Please elaborate your question a bit. Question is very vague.

Comment: I put pictures in the folder where my project is located, but when I write the name in the src section, I cannot put it on my site.

Comment: Your picture I assume is in this path: /public/img/manzara.jpg  or  /storage/app/public/img/manzara.jpg ?

Comment: Yep is in this path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is the public folder, change your  tag as below:

```
<img src="{{asset('/img/manzara.jpg')}}" class="card-img" alt="...">
```

Comment: Ahh yes here it solved the problem. Thanks for your help :)